# Session timeout on database call in ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework 4.3

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, session-timeout

I am developing classified ads application in ASP.NET MVC3 using Entity Framework 4.3 for database.

I am facing problem when user `session` is active and execute any database query by `entity framework` then `application session time's out` unexpectedly.

Note that the query gets execute successfully and I can see my results as well but after a little while asp.net session terminates.

This only happen when I host my application to the live server (Arvixe). On my Local IIS it is working fine.

If I use any other source for database query then it is working fine.

I have also reset `session time-out` in web.config.
I am using `MYSQL`.
Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you doing with the asp.net session? Do you really need it?

Comment: Yes off course I am storing user information..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting values for `wait_timeout` & `interactive_timeout` in MySQL configuration file `my.cnf` as:

```
interactive_timeout = 120
wait_timeout = 120
```

then restart MySQL server.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this is not the db session it is the asp.net session the times out. My query gets executes in a fraction of second but once it is executed something goes wrong with my application session. I can understand that query has not to do any thing with application session but it only happens in case of Entity Framework. It seems like the application pool is getting recycled or  something else I am not sure.

Comment: Is there any solution...I have done lot of search but cant figure out!

Comment: no idea about asp.net. as per database is concerned that's the only solution I can think of. don't forget to mark up and accept answer.